# How to kill or rollback active transaction?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How can I kill or rollback, uncommitted transaction?

I am listing my active transactions with the following sql:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_session_transactions
```

My result is:

```
session_id  transaction_id       transaction_descriptor enlist_count is_user_transaction is_local is_enlisted is_bound
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
54          117260               0x0100000036000000     0            1                   1        0           0
```

I dont want to kill the session (54)...

Thanks all

Comment: I don't think you can. I guess you could try and engineer an error that stops the transaction and if `XACT_ABORT` is on it would automatically rollback but what's the point? Why not kill the spid?

Comment: i dont want to kill spid because i dont want to kill user's session but i guess i have to do it...

i dont have any opinion.

Comment: He probably doesn't want the user's connection dropped by killing the session.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't kill/rollback a transaction from another session without killing the owner session.

I think, allowing to kill/rollback a transaction from another user's session means many design and security rule violations because it requires entering another user session (in the context of the current sql server engine design). That's probably why it is not implemented.

Answer (score 26):

To clear all transaction, Use this only as a temp solution

```
ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName

SET SINGLE_USER

WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

ALTER DATABASE DatabaseName

SET MULTI_USER;
```

refer [this site](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/11/sql-server-alter-database-dbname-set-single_user-with-rollback-immediate/) for more info

Points to check - it also rollbacks committed transactions

Comment: use this only as a temp solution, as this will cancel out all transations

Comment: SQL Server 12.0 -- "ALTER DATABASE statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction."

Comment: i found this on ( sql authority .com something) please refer that site for further details....

Comment: Thank you, that helped in an emergency situation ;)

Comment: I tried this code, and realized that it also rollbacks committed transactions. I don't know if it rollbacks for current session. It is a good temporary solution and it made my day.

Comment: @AlicanUzun as rollbacking committed transactions (as you mentioned) usability was limited to some very special scenarios.